# Minimum mean square error linear estimator of uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, mean-square-error

There is a uniformly distributed Y scalar observation of [−0.5, 0.5]. Parameter X is an observation function that will be estimated. X = cos(2πY). How to determine the MMSE linear estimator of X?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show your attempts. That will be helpful to provide an answer.